# Why is this giving me a logical error?

Tags: c

I started learning C a couple of days ago and now that have covered basics I am trying to make a small text-based game.

Just after making this menu function I tried to run my application and for some reason it's not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int menu() {
    char *start;
    printf("Welcome to my game\n Type START to begin or EXIT to quit: ");

    while (strcmp(start, "start") != 0 && strcmp(start, "exit") != 0) {
        scanf("%s", &start);

        if (strcmp(start, "start") == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else
        if (strcmp(start, "exit") == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid command. Try again: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't get too technical with your answers as I'm still very unfamiliar with C and programming itself.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what your expected functionality is vs what's actually happening?

Comment: Dear George, "*it doesn't work*" is the more or less worth error description one could provide. Please be more specific on what does not work, what you get and would you expected to get instead.

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger

Comment: Does your compilation emmit warnings? (Are they actived?)

Comment: You reserve no space to have the characters saved in, create an array for that : `char start[256];`.

Comment: Perhaps, go back an re-read on C-"strings".

Comment: You do a `strcmp` on start before assigning it a value.

Comment: I agree with @alk - you need to learn how C-strings work. PS: the instructions for your game are misleading. It says "Type START ... or EXIT ..." but inside you are trying to compare "start" and "exit". Note that since each character has a value "S" is not the same as "s" and so on. Either fix the instructions or the code (you can also go all upper/lowercase internally to allow both or mixed such as "sTaRT")

Answer (score 1):

You call `scanf("%s",...)` with the address of a pointer to `char*`, this is not the correct type and the pointer is not initialized anyway.  You should make `start` an array and call `scanf` this way:

```
char start[80];

if (scanf("%79s", start) == 1) {
    /* word was read, check its value */
} else {
    /* no word was read, probably at end of file */
}
```

`scanf("%79s, start)` reads and ignores any white space characters from `stdin`, then reads a word of upto 79 bytes into the array pointed to by `start`. Without the `79`, `scanf` would have no way to tell when to stop and could cause a buffer overflow if standard input contains a very long word.  This is a flow that an attacker could take advantage of to make your program run arbitrary code.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int menu(void) {
    char start[80];

    printf("Welcome to my game\n Type START to begin or EXIT to quit: ");

    for (;;) {
        if (scanf("%79s", start) != 1) {
            break;

        if (strcmp(start, "start") == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else
        if (strcmp(start, "exit") == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid command. Try again: ");
        }
    }
    printf("unexpected end of file\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake in this code is that you are comparing char *start with something(start or exit) and it isn't even initiated.

So first of all assign an input value to *start and then proceed with your compares.

An extra tip would be to put your "input word" into a lower case because you are comparing it with "start" and "exit" which are both lowercase, and it differs if you have lets say "Start" instead of "start".
Check ascii table to understand what i am talking about.